# SDL_UpdateRects and not visible changes on xcb_get_image_reply

Tags: sdl, x11, xcb

Application is using SDL 1.2.15 (cannot be upgraded) and draws itself using `SDL_UpdateRects`. After such paint it notifies another app which tries to get screenshot by `xcb_get_image_reply`. Problem is that randomly `xcb_get_image_reply` returns image without expected change. It looks like some data are buffered and screen is not updated at the moment of taking screenshot. Is there some simple method to ensure the screen is updated after `SDL_UpdateRects`, preferably using SDL or XCB? (I would like to avoid calling `xrefresh`).

Comment: Have you tried [forcing the issue using `SDL_UpdateRect(screen, 0, 0, 0, 0)`](https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlflip.html)?

Comment: What flags passed to `SetVideoMode`? Is doublebuf or async there?

Comment: @keltar `SDL_SetVideoMode( 1680, 1050, 16, SDL_SWSURFACE )`

Comment: @genpfault I need to check it, we call it but only if everything needs to be repainted.

Comment: How does it notify the other app? Does this notification go through the X11 server, or is it out-of-band? If so, how do you guarantee proper synchronisation between the two? For just-XCB, the function you are looking for is `xcb_aux_sync()`.

Comment: @UliSchlachter App 'A' (which uses SDL) sends text message through socket to app 'B', and then app 'B' uses XCB to get screenshot. I assume that in this case `xcb_aux_sync` will not help.

Comment: X11 also works by sending messages through a socket to the X11 server. So I guess what you are seeing is: You send both messages (X11 server: please display this; app B: please take screenshot). Sometimes app B manages to take a screenshot before the X11 server can react to that other message. In this case, `xcb_aux_sync` would help: It would be: "X11 server, please display this and then tell me when you are done". *wait*. Okay, now app B, you can take a screenshot.